# Use textract on PDF file located on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to apply textract to a pdf file hosted on Google Cloud Storage.

I have used and parsed a txt file already(everything works fine) with download_as_string()

```py
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucket-for-pdf')
blob = bucket.get_blob('keywords.txt')
keywords_file = blob.download_as_string().decode('utf8')
```

How download_as_string() works exactly? Can I do something similar to pdf file? Something like this

```py
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucket-for-pdf')
blob = bucket.get_blob(file_name)
file_name = blob.download_to_file(file_name)
return textract.process(file_name, language='eng',
                        encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

The above code cause error:

```sh
self._stream.write(chunk)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Update: So far the only work around is download the files and after I am done I delete them.

Answer (score 2):

The `download_to_file` method takes a file object, not a file name. Try something like:

```py
file_name = "/tmp/my-file"
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucket-for-pdf')

with open(file_name, "wb") as file_obj:
    blob.download_to_file(file_obj)

return textract.process(file_name, language='eng', encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: let me give it a try